# Lowercase string to sentence case

Tags: c++, wstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert first letter in string to uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530529/convert-first-letter-in-string-to-uppercase)

How do I convert a string to title case in C++
"hello world" to "Hello World" . The string can even have multibyte characters

Comment: Are you looking for a library function or are you asking for a description of an algorithm that does so?

Comment: Since you mentioned multi-byte, I've retagged this as [tag:wstring]. If this is incorrect, you can change it back, and be more specific as to what you are using. (Give an example.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you follow the advice on your previous question, [Convert first letter in string to uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530529/convert-first-letter-in-string-to-uppercase), all you need to do is split the string into one word each, and uppercase it.

```
std::wstring s = L"iron maiden";

if(s.length() > 0)
    s[0] = toupper(s[0]);

for(std::wstring::iterator it = s.begin() + 1; it != s.end(); ++it)
{
    if(!isalpha(*(it - 1)) &&
       islower(*it))
    {
        *it = toupper(*it);
    }
}
```

Basically, you just have to write/use a parser.

Comment: What happens when you try to access `*(it - 1)` on the first iteration ?