# Uppercase substring

Tags: c++

```
ret += ": " + param.substr(tmp, rtmp);
```

I've tried and searched something useful to capitalize the first letter of the line above(substring) but had no success.

```
std::string ret = "stackoverflow";

    if(param.length())
    {
        trimString(param);

        size_t tmp = 0, rtmp = param.length();
        if(param[0] == '"')
            tmp = 1;

        if(param[rtmp] == '"')
            rtmp -= 1;

        ret += ": " + param.substr(tmp, rtmp);
    }
```

How it works?

Text

```
stackoverflow "whatever
```

Output

```
stackoverflow: whatever
```

And this is what i'm looking for

```
stackoverflow: Whatever
```

Comment: I suggest you should post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm confused.  Where do you think you're uppercasing a letter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert first letter in string to uppercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530529/convert-first-letter-in-string-to-uppercase)

Comment: Post edited. @Hot Licks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take

```
 ret += ": " + param.substr(tmp, rtmp);
```

And, first, extract the substring into a temporary variable, then uppercase the first letter:

```
 std::string s=param.substr(tmp, rtmp);

 s[0]=toupper(s[0]);

 ret += ": " + s;
```