# Capitalize first letter of string

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to capitalize the first character of a `std::string`, using the same method [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530529/convert-first-letter-in-string-to-uppercase). For example for the following program

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name = "foobar";
    name[0] = std::toupper(name[0]);
    std::cout << name;
}
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
Foobar
```

When I [compile this online](http://cpp.sh/8vjl) (using GCC 4.9.2) I get the correct output **without any warnings**. However, when I compile the same code in Visual Studio 2013, I get a warning during the assignment back from `toupper`

```
warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'char', possible loss of data
```

Is the above method valid according to the C++ standard or is the warning correct? Otherwise is this just a false warning by Visual Studio?

Comment: My bet is that GCC and Clang recognize that using `toupper` outside the range of an unsigned char is UB so the do not emit an warning where MSVS does not make a special exemption.

Comment: Which I now now is not correct based on: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec8aca500d4222a2

Comment: Apparently you have to specify `-Wconversion` if you want clang and gcc to warn about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is correct as far the types go; the type of `std::toupper` as defined in the standard is:

```
int toupper( int ch );
```

Mostly because it's a remnant from the dark C ages (the `cctype` header is a hint at that).

However, this is just a part of the story. There's *another* `toupper` residing in the `locale` header:

```
template< class charT >
charT toupper( charT ch, const locale& loc );
```

This one shouldn't give you any warnings. If you're not sure what locale to provide, `std::locale()` will give you the default one.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) comes from the C standard, not C++, and has an annoying interface in that it takes and returns an `int` not a `char`. Using `static_cast<char>(std::toupper(name[0]))` will suit you.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is correct, compiler will implicitly cast from int to char but this might cause lost of data in some cases. To see warning under `gcc` you need to add -Wconversion compiler option. Which will generate:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8:13: warning: conversion to '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type {aka char}' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     name[0] = std::toupper(name[0]);
             ^
Foobar
```

Why it is not present when -Wall is set, read here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion

> Why isn't Wconversion enabled by -Wall or at least by -Wextra?
>
> Implicit conversions are very common in C. This tied with the fact
>   that there is no data-flow in front-ends (see next question) results
>   in hard to avoid warnings for perfectly working and valid code.
>   Wconversion is designed for a niche of uses (security audits, porting
>   32 bit code to 64 bit, etc.) where the programmer is willing to accept
>   and workaround invalid warnings. Therefore, it shouldn't be enabled if
>   it is not explicitly requested.